# for(i=i-1;i>=0;i++) How does this line works?

Tags: c, syntax

I read a code to convert decimal to binary. In that, after calculating and storing the binary number in an array in reverse, there was a for loop to print the array in reverse.
It goes like,

```
for(i=i-1;i>=0;i++)
printf("%d",b[i]);
```

Can anyone explain me how does the initialization part works?

Comment: If `i` was `-4` before the loop starts, the initialization part sets `i` to `-5`; if `i` was `2` or greater you enter an (almost-)infinite loop (UB)

Comment: `i` is assigned one less than what is was before. The increment part doesn't make sense, though. It should be `i--` otherwise the loop either will run or won't because a signed integer will never overflow from nonnegative to negative (given that signed overflow in C is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

In your case we should certainly have `i--` instead of `i++`.

Just consider the below structure of `for` loops:

```
for (init ;condition; step)
```

The `init` state will be consider just one time at the beginning, each time `condition` checks and if it satisfies it will go to the block and at the end `step` will execute. Then we can rewrite the given loop as below:

```
i = i-1;
while ( i >= 0 ) {
   printf("%d",b[i]);
   i--;
}
```

Then in your case if we have `i` is equal length of `b` array, then your code will print all elements in the `b` in reverse order.

Comment: Well then how can I tell what is the value of i in the first line? Cause it cannot be 0, right?

Comment: Well if it's 0, it wont go inside of the for. So, it's safe, but not working. 
You have initialization of `i` before this part. Would be better to just write **for ( int i = size_of(b) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )**